# Global spinner not displaying with routing events

Tags: angular, routes, spinner

I have this code on my app component HTML

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-progress-spinner>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the TS

```
export class AppComponent {
  loading: boolean;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
      this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent)
    })
  }
  checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log(this.loading)
    }
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false
      console.log(this.loading)

    }

  }
}
```

I learned this technique with [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ) by Deborah Kurata. But I never see the spinner and I have lots of images in my app when loading the page. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

})
```

With the onPush changedetection, the images don't appear, so I'm kind of lost here...

EDIT:

App-routing:

```
    //const adminModule = ()=> import('./admin/admin.module').then(m=>m.AdminModule);
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '', component:ShellComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService] },
          //{path: 'admin', loadChildren: adminModule},
          {path: 'detail/:id', component: DetailComponent, },
    
          {path: '', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},
          {path: 'table', component:ListBooksComponent},
          {path: 'selection', component: SelectionComponent, },
  {path:'edit/:id', component:RegisterComponent, canDeactivate:[EditGuardService]},

    
        ]
      },
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path:'edit/:id', component:RegisterComponent},
      {path:'register', component: RegisterComponent}
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: First of all the loading of images will not stop the navigation and is not part of the navigation life cycle. Are you by any chance using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your app component?

Comment: no, im using the default one, but i can try you suggestion

Answer (score 1):

First of all the loading of images will not stop the navigation and is not part of the navigation life cycle.

Are you by any chance using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your app component? If so, one way to do it, is to make it an `Observable`. Which is a cleaner solution anyways:

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async"></mat-progress-spinner>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  readonly loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.router.events.pipe(
    map((event) => this.checkRouterEvent(event))
  );

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): boolean {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      return true;
    }

    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

---

However, keep in mind that the only way you will be able to actually see the spinner, if the router has some resolving/guarding/loading to do. Which basically means:

1. Resolving: These are [resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#resolve) declared on the path you are navigating to. If these are async, like http calls, your spinner will show for the duration of the resolving
2. Guarding: These are the [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate), [`CanActivateChild`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild), [`CanLoad`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) and the lesser known [`CanDeactivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) guards on your route config. Same counts here, if these are async there will be a spinner
3. Loading: This is the [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading) of your feature modules. This is a path defined with the [`loadChildren`](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#loadChildren) config. While the application is requesting the module, it will delay the router for as long as it's loading

If your route config does not have any of these 3 things, or they are not async, you will not see a spinner

Comment: ok, thanks for the complete answer, Ill try and get back

Comment: with your code (i replace it with mine) I get this error: `Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`

Comment: I understand your logic as the video also, but my implementation did not work

Comment: @Mellville I wrongly copied your `checkRouterEvent`. I did not change the return type of this method. I've updated my answer. Are you sure you have any of those 3 things I mentioned in your route config. Can you post your route config? Also, can you check with a `<h1>Test</h1>` or without the `*ngIf`, to see if something is actually visible

Comment: im sorry for the late comment. I will try that solution

Comment: check my edit, it has the route congig. Im puzzled because I did the tutorial step by step, as you can see on the link I provided

Comment: @Mellville so the only thing that can cause a spinner is your `AuthGuardService` and `EditGuardService`